# @FontFace, using downloaded font

Tags: html, fonts, font-face

I am trying to import a font that I downloaded to my code using @font-face, the text is reading right however it's bypassing the downloaded font in my font family and going straight to the backup font, "Cursive". I don't know why this is happening because I've triple checked that it is linked to the right folder. Please let me know any thoughts you might have. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yR3t.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

### @font-face usage

With the @font-face rule,you do not have to use one of the "web-safe" fonts anymore like font-family:'Poppins','serif'.The will be Stored as a Local font like font-family : Times New Roman,serif

In the @font-face rule you must first define a name for the font (e.g. myFirstFont), and then point to the font file.

To use the font for an HTML element, refer to the name of the font (myFirstFont) defined in the font-family property:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: myFirstFont;
      src: url(sansation_light.woff);
    }

div {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).